# How do I auto format Ruby or .erb files in VS Code?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, visual-studio-code

I press <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Visual Studio Code for macOS, the shortcut to [Format Document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings), to format a file called `foo.rb` or `foo.html.erb`.

Instead of formatting the document it prints out this letter: `Ï`

How do I get it to format the document?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can set format associations in VSCode, so .erb files would be treated like .html.

Go to File->Preferences->Settings->Click ... in top right corner->Open settings.json

Then add this piece of code to your settings.json

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.html.erb": "html"
}
```

This is how I solved this problem. It will remove some of the code highlights but will autoformat HTML templates like an HTML document.

Comment: This removes the autocomplete for rb elements like `link_to`

Comment: This suggestion keeps coming up but it's just... bad. erb files are not merely html files and they should not be formatted as such. Use `"*.erb": "erb"` and install a formatter that knows what erb is.

Comment: @MohamedAbuGalala how do you get autocomplete in views?

Comment: @cikatomo I didn't want to install a ruby package to format the project, so I installed an extension that formats the selection as HTML. But I don't recommend doing so.

Comment: @cikatomo  what I do recommend is https://stackoverflow.com/a/75898836/5055925

Comment: Worked great. A reminder: to get to settings.json press command + shift + p and type 'settings', then `Preferences: Open User Settings` should be one of the first to come up.

Answer (score 25):

You're going to need all of these settings in VS Code's `settings.json` file:

```
"ruby.rubocop.onSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSaveTimeout": 5000,
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"files.associations": {
    "*.erb": "erb"
},
```

Save the settings file. Install the "ruby-rubocop" and "ERB Formatter/Beautify" extensions on VS Code. Follow the documentation on both of those extensions to install their `gem` dependencies. Restart VS Code.

Format-on-save functionality will only trigger if the file is actually saved (which only happens if you change the file). Saving a file that has no changes will not trigger format-on-save.

Comment: Is that supposed to also have syntax highlighting? If so, it is not working for me. :/

Comment: I don't think that the extensions I've mentioned do syntax highlighting, no. I somehow have Ruby syntax highlighting even when I disable all extensions, but you probably want to look specifically for an extension that mentions syntax highlighting.

Comment: I just wanted to add to this that if you have multiple installations you may need to specify the absolute path in settings to your htmlbeautifier (setting is called `Vscode-erb-beautify` and to Ruby > Rubocop settings for rubocop.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using prettier to format your html/css/js files, it is worth trying [prettier-erb-plugin](https://github.com/adamzapasnik/prettier-plugin-erb). Just add to your `.prettierrc`:

```json
  "plugins": ["@prettier/plugin-ruby", "prettier-plugin-erb"]
```

Or install it with yarn:

```
yarn add -D prettier @prettier/plugin-ruby prettier-plugin-erb
```

And make sure that VSCode uses local version of prettier from `node_modules` (or, you probably can install these plugins globally as well). Prettier VSCode plugin usually declared itself as default formatter, but just in case, make sure that in your `settings.json` is **NOT** written something like:

```json
    "[erb]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "aliariff.vscode-erb-beautify"
    },
```

Comment: @prettier/plugin-ruby is exceedingly broken these days

Answer (score 5):

## If you have no code formatting

That is, when you hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format your code, vscode says something like:

[image: There is no formatter for erb files installed]

1. [install a formatter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHVqcN3S_jI&t=2m40s) by clicking on the 'Extensions' tab on the left hand side of vscode, searching for 'ERB Formatter/Beautify' (by Ali Ariff), and installing it.
2. Run `gem install htmlbeautifier`
3. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search for

```
Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
```

It should open a file that has a your JSON settings in it; something like this:

```json
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
}
```

4. Add this to the settings.json file you opened in the previous step

```json
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html.erb": "erb"
      }
```

Your finished file might look like this:

```json
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html.erb": "erb"
      }
}
```

5. Close and reopen vscode and it should now let you format with <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

## If you have no syntax highlighting for erb files

The extension called 'ruby' will solve that.

1. Click on the 'Extensions' tab on the right hand side of vscode.
2. type in `ruby`
3. Install the ruby extension by Peng Lv
4. You may need to restart vscode
5. All done!
   [image]

## Reference

- More info in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHVqcN3S_jI&t=1m55s)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Rufo](https://github.com/ruby-formatter/rufo) to format your Ruby code. It is an opinionated formatter (like [Prettier](https://prettier.io) is for JS, if you are familiar with it).

You can use the [vscode-rufo](https://github.com/bessey/vscode-rufo) extension to integrate it with VSCode.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS Code version 1.25.0-insiders

Comment: Do `gem install rufo` after installing the plugin, then it will work.

Comment: Even when I installed the gem, it still says that there is no document formatter for 'erb'-files installed. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Update the `settings.json` of Visual Studio code:

`File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"`

Or in these paths in your OS

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

From [Visual Studio Code Ruby extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) documentation they recommend to use as an initial configuration:

```
"ruby.useBundler": true, //run non-lint commands with bundle exec
"ruby.useLanguageServer": true, // use the internal language server (see below)
"ruby.lint": {
  "rubocop": {
    "useBundler": true // enable rubocop via bundler
  },
  "reek": {
    "useBundler": true // enable reek via bundler
  }
},
"ruby.format": "rubocop" // use rubocop for formatting
```

Look at the [linting](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/blob/master/docs/linting.md) documentation too for further improvements. Plus as mentioned previously, you can add that .erb should be treated as .html:

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.html.erb": "html"
}
```

Comment: changing the files.associations to "html" as you suggested caused more problems than it fixed, in my environment

Comment: You don't want to format erb files as if they are only html files.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `rubocop` instead of `rufo`.

At the beginning, I used `rufo`. However, I met the issue

```rb
{
  boo: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
}
```

it always format it for me as

```rb
{
  boo: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
}
```

add two `,`, behind `c: 3` and `boo: {}`. It is that makes my `rubocop` fail always.

As for, I use the `rubocop` in the project. Why not use it format my codes directly!

If you are interested, you can do as the following:

install the plugin [VSCode ruby](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby) and then add the following snippets in the the `settings.json`

```
  "ruby.format": "rubocop",
  "ruby.intellisense": "rubyLocate",
  "ruby.useBundler": true,
  "ruby.lint": {
    "rubocop": {
      "useBundler": true
    }
  },
```

save it. It works~~(I wish you)

Comment: You can disable trailing commas in rufo https://github.com/ruby-formatter/rufo/blob/master/docs/settings.md

Comment: Or enable them in Rubocop.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (March 2019) I think prettier with prettier-ruby are the best options: it can handle Ruby, ERB (as HTML), JS, and many many more.

```sh
prettier script.rb # will show you the formatted script
prettier --write script.rb # will overwrite the file with the formatted script
```

You can use the Prettier VS Code plugin to do that automatically: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

https://github.com/prettier/plugin-ruby

Comment: I don't think prettier-ruby handles `.erb` files.

Comment: Prettier does not handle `.erb` files. It is currently filed as [feature request](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-ruby/issues/371) to which you can subscribe to notifications to know when/if it will be implemented and add your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install htmlbeautifier
```

through the search functionality provided in the editor with Ctrl +Shift+ P (or Command + Shift + P on Mac), and then searching for **format document**.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to:

1. Install ruby-rubocop in VS Code
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
3. Search for Editor: Default Formatter and select "misogi.ruby-rubocop"
4. Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts
5. Search for Ruby: autocorrect by rubocop. There you have the shortcut to run rubocop in order to automatic format your ruby code following your rubocop settings.

You may also right click in your ruby file and you will find the "Format Document" option, which triggers "Ruby: autocorrect by rubocop" once ruby-rubocop is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install either the [official ruby prettier plugin](https://github.com/prettier/plugin-ruby) or the [community erb prettier plugin](https://github.com/adamzapasnik/prettier-plugin-erb) and let Prettier do its job.

You can follow this article as a [quick start](https://dev.to/drayeleo/installing-the-ruby-plugin-for-prettier-in-vs-code-2m6c)

Or you can use the [ERB Formatter/Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliariff.vscode-erb-beautify) extension.

Comment: The prettier-plugin-erb you mentioned seems to no longer be developed, but is not deprecated either.

Answer (score -5):

To format your ruby files, you don't need any extra plugin, you can just map some keys to do "editor.action.reindentLines"

If you use vscode-vim plugin, you can add this to your settings:

```
 "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["=", "="],
            "commands": ["editor.action.reindentlines"]
        }
    ],
```

Then in normal vim mode, `==` will reformat your file.